# Using Updatepanel in sharepoint 2013 web part

Tags: sharepoint-2013

We are facing problem related to updatepanel in sharepoint 2013. we have a sample webpart that includs a label and a button, we want to write somthing to label in click event of button without refreshing the whole page. Our sample code is as followed :

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text="Loaded" Visible="true"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" OnClick="btn_Click"/>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btn" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>    

    protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbl.Text = "BUTTON CLICKED !";
        lbl.Visible = true;
    }
```

We have tried the solution mentioned on this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb861877.aspx) but could not achieve our goal.

Any solution for this problem along with sample code will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As I noticed the Content Search webpart and the update panel cannot work together on SharePoint 2013 for some reason. If I add my custom update panel webpart to stand alone page than working the updapanel  well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to play with UpdateMode and ChildrenAsTriggers? Like this for example:

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel id="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" 
         UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" >
```